# Is there any option for avoid the & symbol in Angular 4 HTTP request?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Am using `HTTP` request to store the data in my database. For that, I just used the following code.

```js
    const form = '&inputdata=' + myinput + '&rf_date=' + rf_date;
    return this.http.post(this.rootUrl, form, {headers : this.reqHeader});
```

here, `inputdata` =  "Files & Folders". When am running this only "Files" storing in my DB. "& Folders" is not stored. Because of the '&' delimiter.

So, is there any option to resolve this issue in Angular 4?

Comment: Use encodeURIComponent to include the special characters. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should) use the body of the request to send to the server. [Official http client angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http)

You can send a json object to your backend like this:

```
const form = {inputdata: myinput, rf_date: rf_date};
return this.http.post(this.rootUrl, form, {headers : this.reqHeader});
```

Prefer standard formats like json when you are designing your api. Depending on the api of your choice, it should be fairly easy to map/deserialize the json object to your backend structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `encodeURIComponent(val)` to encode your variables (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

i.e.

```js
  const form = '&inputdata=' + encodeURIComponent(myinput) + '&rf_date=' + rf_date;
  return this.http.post(this.rootUrl, form, {headers : this.reqHeader});
```